# LibGDX drawing text by 3d coordinate

Tags: text, 3d, libgdx

I've been trying out basic 3d and physics with LibGDX lately and I came across a problem that I couldn't solve.

In my game right now I have a player and a boss that deal damage to each other and health bars for each. I want the damage dealt by each entity to show up as text over the entity that was dealt the damage. The player is always centered so drawing text over him is easy, but the enemy can be in several different positions and I'm not sure how to translate his position into a way to draw text directly over him.

Example images:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwGxnbhXyOv2UjVVRXFwc3MzeUU/view?usp=sharing
[image: Image 1]
and https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwGxnbhXyOv2aE1EbGt2Q25hZFU/view?usp=sharing
[image: Image 2]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your text drawn with a 2D orthographic camera, separate from your scene's 3d camera?

Comment: No, right now it's drawn with the same PerspectiveCamera as my models

Comment: Can't you take the boss's world position, add half his height to the Y component, and draw it there?

Comment: My main issue with it comes with depth. When my player has a higher Z coordinate, the boss is drawn higher on the screen and I'm not sure how to factor in depth with the XY coordinates of the font

Comment: Are you drawing the health stuff with ModelBatch or DecalBatch or something else? You basically just need to disable depth testing and draw that stuff last, but the way to do it varies depending on what you're using to draw them.

Comment: Did you use Ashley Entity Component system? Can you share code?